# Getting entity properties from Key in google app engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm passing a model entity's id in a url in on handler, and in another I simply need to look up the property value from that id.

```
class Pdf(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class InputHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('cert_form.html')

    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')

        if name:
            a = Pdf(name=name)
            a.put()
            self.redirect('/key=%s' % a.key())
        else:
            error = "Please enter your full name."
            self.render('cert_form.html')

class PDFHandler(Handler):
    def get(self, id):
        a = db.Key.from_path('Pdf', id)


        self.response.write(a.name())

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', InputHandler),
    (r'/key=(.)+', PDFHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.redirect('%s' % str(a.key().id()))` (besides the total redundancy of %s and str -- lose that str call!-) redirects to a URL that's a pretty arbitrary string.  How are you routing that, presumably to `PDFHandler`, so it can get its `id`?

A more sensible and common approach would be to redirect to, say,

```
'/pdfh?id=%s' % urllib2.urlencode(whatever)
```

or probably better

```
'/pdfh?k=%s' % a.key().urlsafe()
```

and use `self.request.get` in the handler to get the id (or probably better the url-safe form of the key, ready for a `ndb.Key(urlsafe=...` call to give you the actual key to use).

These approaches make routing obvious -- with your very peculiar approach, I need to see the routing to explain exactly why it's not working (the chance that such weird routing would work are not zero, but, very minimal:-).  BTW, I'll need to see both the first layer of routing in your app.yaml, and the second layer in your Python code.

Or, you could just switch to a more sensible URL scheme, and be done in 23 seconds:-).

Comment: I know this sound REALLY dumb now, but I tried both your approaches and I keep getting variations of AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlencode' or AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'urlsafe'. Really my problem I think is I have no idea how to get attributes from the datastore, not just the entities. I need the string name, not the model object (or whatever it's called in datastore)

Comment: @CameronSima, the string `name` is **in** the entity (which you call a model object) -- once you have the entity bound to variable `a`, `a.name` is the string you want.

Comment: That's what I thought, but what that returns for me is <bound method Key.name of datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'PDF', u'5576722976079872', _app=u'dev~your-app-id')> how do I simply get the value?

Comment: OK, now something genuinely weird is going on...when I try to fetch a.name, no matter what I enter for a, it returns 'w'